# Phalcon 3 - Centos 7 Cpanel EasyApache 4 - php5.6

Tags: cpanel, phalcon

I am trying to install Phalcon with:

```
curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/phalcon/stable/script.rpm.sh | sudo bash

yum install php56u-phalcon
```

but I get dependency errors:

```
Error: Package: php56u-phalcon-3.0.1-14.ius.el7.centos.x86_64 (phalcon_stable)
           Requires: php56u-pdo(x86-64)

Error: Package: php56u-phalcon-3.0.1-14.ius.el7.centos.x86_64 (phalcon_stable)
           Requires: php56u-common(x86-64)

Error: Package: php56u-phalcon-3.0.1-14.ius.el7.centos.x86_64 (phalcon_stable)
           Requires: php56u(api) = 20131106

Error: Package: php56u-phalcon-3.0.1-14.ius.el7.centos.x86_64 (phalcon_stable)
           Requires: php56u(zend-abi) = 20131226
```

These libraries are installed but with the modifier "ea-" of easy apache.

How I can install Phalcon 3 in Centos 7 cpanel easyapache 4?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like phalcon expecting you to have php56 from ius repository.
I've had same error, but because my php56 came from remi repo instead I had no modifier on php* packages, for example `php-pdo` package instead of `php56u-pdo`.

I've solved it this way:

```
yum install php-phalcon3
```

(can be php-phalcon2, php7-php-palcon3 and so on - see `yum search phalcon`)
In your case this probably won't help, because you have ea- modifier on php*.
Possibly somebody more experienced with yum could suggest how to solve this conflict. But you still have two more options:

- compile phalcon.so from source code (described here: https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon).
- install php from ius Centos 7 repository.

UPD: I must add that I was unable to make phalcon (php-phalcon* from remi dedicated repos for php5.6 and php7) to work - I've got "child pid exit signal Segmentation fault".

As a general rule: your phalcon package should be from the same repo from which you've installed php and php-* packages(e.g. php-mysqlnd, php-pdo).
 In my opinion, if you wnat to be sure that your library will work on particular machine the best way is to compile it on this or similar machine.

Comment: I also tried to compile Phalcon, but had the same problem with php libraries installed by easyapache 4, all with the "ea-*".
In the end I compiled Phalcon on another server with centos 7 and php56, then I copied phalcon.so to this server and it worked.

Thanks for your time

Comment: The funniest thing is that I've came to that too.